# How to avoid crash on python socket server if SSL message is not received

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I have coded a server with python ssl.socket and whenever i receive a message that is not SSL the server crashes with this following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./server.py", line 88, in 
>      keyfile="server.key")
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 936, in wrap_socket
>      ciphers=ciphers)
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in **init**
>      self.do_handshake()
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 833, in do_handshake
>      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>   **ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:579)**

Here is the server code:

```
            #!/usr/bin/python
            import socket
            import ssl
            import sys
            import os
            import MySQLdb
            import logging

            from function import encrypt

            # Create a TCP/IP socket
            bindsocket = socket.socket()
            bindsocket.bind(('', 10023))
            bindsocket.listen(5)

            # Bind the socket to the port
            print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on port %s' % bindsocket.bind
            def process_data(connstream, data):
                data1 = data.rstrip()
                data_list = data1.split(",")
                print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data_list
                if data1:
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'Checking Database'
                    con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX')
                    cursor = con.cursor()
                    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hostname WHERE systemname = '%s'" % data_list[1])
                    rowsz = cursor.rowcount
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    if data_list[0] == "server":
                        if rowsz == 1:
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Updating Hostname:"%s"' % data_list[1]
                            cursor.execute("UPDATE hostname set systemname='%s',domain='%s',vendor='%s',model='%s',machinetype='%s',os='%s',osrelease='%s',machineserial='%s' where systemname = '%s'" % (data_list[1], data_list[2], data_list[3], data_list[4], data_list[5], data_list[6], data_list[7], data_list[8], data_list[1]))
                            cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM hostname where systemname = '%s'" % data_list[1])
                            detids = cursor.fetchone()
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Updating datacenter for ID: "%s"' % detids[0]
                            cursor.execute("UPDATE details set datacenter='%s' where detid = '%s'"  % (data_list[9], detids[0]))
                        elif rowsz < 1:
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Inserting Hostname:"%s"' % data_list[1]
                            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO hostname (systemname, domain, vendor, model, machinetype, os, osrelease, machineserial) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (data_list[1], data_list[2], data_list[3], data_list[4], data_list[5], data_list[6], data_list[7], data_list[8]))
                            default= 'default'
                            defaultint = 1
                            cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM hostname where systemname = '%s'" % data_list[1])
                            detids = cursor.fetchone()
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Updating details for id: "%s"' % detids[0]
                            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO details (detid, inservice, globalstatus, managedby, machineconsole, passwd, application, datacenter, rackspace, mlog) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (detids[0], defaultint, defaultint, default, default, default, default, default, default, default))
                        else:
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Nothing updated'
                    elif data_list[0] == "network":
                        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM hostname where systemname = '%s'" % data_list[1])
                        detids = cursor.fetchone()
                        cursor.execute("SELECT * from network where netid = '%s'" % detids[0])
                        rowszz = cursor.rowcount
                        print >>sys.stderr, 'Count : "%s"' % rowszz
                        if rowszz >= 1:
                            print >>sys.stderr, 'Updating network details for id: "%s"' % detids[0]
                            for i in xrange(2, len(data_list), 5):
                                if data_list[i]:
                                    sqlcmd = "UPDATE network set netid='{val1}', interface='{val2}', ipaddress='{val3}', macaddress='{val4}', gateway='{val5}', interfacestatus='{val6}' WHERE interface = '{val2}' AND netid = '{val1}'".format(val1=detids[0], val2=data_list[i], val3=data_list[i+1], val4=data_list[i+2], val5=data_list[i+3], val6=data_list[i+4])
                                    cursor.execute(sqlcmd)
                                else:
                                    print >>sys.stderr, 'Inserting network details for id: "%s"' % detids[0]
                                    for i in xrange(2, len(data_list), 5):
                                        if data_list[i]:
                                            sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO network (netid, interface, ipaddress, macaddress, gateway, interfacestatus) VALUES ('{val1}', '{val2}', '{val3}', '{val4}', '{val5}', '{val6}')".format(val1=detids[0], val2=data_list[i], val3=data_list[i+1], val4=data_list[i+2], val5=data_list[i+3], val6=data_list[i+4])
                                            cursor.execute(sqlcmd)
                    elif data_list[0] == "rootpwd":
                        print >>sys.stderr, 'Updating root pwd for :"%s"' % data_list[1]
                        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM hostname where systemname = '%s'" % data_list[1])
                        detsids = cursor.fetchone()
                        ciphertext = encrypt(data_list[2])
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE details set passwd='%s' where detid = '%s'" % (ciphertext, detsids[0]))
                else:
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                return False

            def deal_with_client(connstream):
                 break
            data = connstream.read()

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="server.crt",
                                 keyfile="server.key")
    try:
        deal_with_client(connstream)

    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

and the client is sending information to server like this :

> **/bin/echo $variable,$variable,$variable | /usr/bin/openssl s_client -quiet -connect hostname:port**

its there a way to avoid server crash if the message it receives doesn't make sense for the server or if message received its wrong format ?

thank you.

Comment: Catch the error?

Comment: May be you can sniff the incoming msg to determine if it is TLS/SSL and base on that bifurcate the logic to SSL and non SSL connection.

Comment: the error was generated intentionally to test the stability of server by sending a non SSL message to server hence the question if someone is messing around can crash my server .. also if i do a nc -z hostname:port will crash the server which means is prone to crash if someone scan's the IP on all ports

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the code i have posted its complete and if you are going to send /bin/echo example | /usr/bin/openssl s_client -quiet -connect hostname:port to it its going to crash with the error i posted since the message is NOT SSL and the server its expecting a SSL message i think you miss out the question and you haven't read the entire post at all

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i apologize , i haven't noticed that copy paste did not work for the entire server.py file.